# Execute if-statement after fixed amount of time

Tags: c#, if-statement

I don't know if this is an easy question or not.

I'm trying to write a single function that slows down the player and returns them to normal speed after a certain amount of time. I founds some answers online but they all use a second function to set a timer, but I'm trying to contain the whole thing in one function.

I've already tried this:

```
public void slowDown(float slowAmount, float durationSlowed)
{
        var playerInfo = player.GetComponent<FPSMovement>();
        playerInfo.speed *= slowAmount;

        float lengthSlowed = Time.time + durationSlowed;

        if(Time.time > lengthSlowed)
        {
                playerInfo.speed /= slowAmount;
        }
}
```

and calling it with:

```
slowDown (0.5f, 2f)
```

It manages to slow down the player, but doesn't return their speed to normal.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you expecting the speed to be reset if you don't reset it?

Comment: You could use a for loop inside of your if statement where you divide by slow Amount until you've reached the start Speed and add a delay as well. But that won't be very pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is unity.

You probably want to do it with IEnumerators and Coroutines. They distribute code to be executed over multiple frames. Something like this:

```
IEnumerator SpeedUp() {
  speed *= 2;
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
  speed /= 2;
}

void Update (){
  if(Input.GetKeyDown(***YOUR KEY HERE***)) {
    StartCoroutine(SpeedUp());
  }
}
```

This will double the speed of your character, wait 2 seconds, and halve it. If you want to add a cooldown to the amount of times you can add speed, just drop a boolean check.